# how to use _sprintf_ and _for_ in R programming

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm a beginner in R programming. I'm trying to use a *for* loop with the *sprintf* function. Without the for loop the function works pretty well:

```
var=2
sprintf("I want to print this number: %d",var)
```

The output:

```
"I want to print this number: 2"
```

Oddly for me, when I use *for* I don't have any outputs:

```
for (var in 1:10)
{
  sprintf('I want to print this number: %d', var)
}
```

Why is this happening? is there another function which can make this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap it in `cat()`:

```
for (var in 1:10)
{
  cat(sprintf('I want to print this number: %d', var), "\n")
}

I want to print this number: 1 
I want to print this number: 2 
I want to print this number: 3 
I want to print this number: 4 
I want to print this number: 5 
I want to print this number: 6 
I want to print this number: 7 
I want to print this number: 8 
I want to print this number: 9 
I want to print this number: 10
```

From `help("sprintf")`:

> Value
>
> A character vector of length that of the longest input.

So `sprintf()` is **returning** a character vector, not **printing** one.
Outside a loop, returning the vector will print it in many contexts.
However, in a context such as a loop, that's insufficient, you also need to tell R to display the returned vector in the console via, e.g., `cat()`.

Comment: I didn't understand, where did you use cat()?

Comment: Just added some info

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the copy-paste error and thanks to @Jan for pointing it out with the helpful edit