# Strange _for_ loop behavior on R programming

Tags: r, for-loop

Based on the answers of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62363528/how-to-use-for-in-the-dataframes-in-r-programming/62363719?noredirect=1#comment110296591_62363719), I tried to write the following codes:

```
for(var in names(Auto)) {print(var)}
```

---

```
"mpg" [1] "cylinders" [1] "displacement" [1] "horsepower" [1] "weight" [1] "acceleration" [1] "year" [1] "origin"
```

Ok, my name variables are in names(Auto), then I moved on:

```
for(var in names(Auto)) 
{
  summary(lm(paste('mpg ~', var), data = Auto))
}
```

---

```
Warning messages:
1: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  the response appeared on the right-hand side and was dropped
2: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  problem with term 1 in model.matrix: no columns are assigned
```

Strangely for one iteration we have:

```
var='cylinders'
summary(lm(paste('mpg ~', var), data = Auto)
```

---

```
Call:
lm(formula = paste("mpg ~", var), data = Auto)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-14.2413  -3.1832  -0.6332   2.5491  17.9168 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  42.9155     0.8349   51.40   <2e-16 ***
cylinders    -3.5581     0.1457  -24.43   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.914 on 390 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6047,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6037 
F-statistic: 596.6 on 1 and 390 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

That's what I wanted for each iteration.

Comment: In the first iteration you have `lm(mpg ~ mpg)`. That's what's causing the problem. Try `for(var in names(Auto)[-1])`

Comment: @duckmayr it didn't show anything

Comment: If you want it to print in a loop, you need to use `print()` or `cat()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62360903/8386140

Comment: @duckmayr it worked thank you very much. One question, why we need the print in _for_ loops and in one iteration it prints perfectly without the _for_ loop? for me we should expect the same result, using for with 100 iterations and do it by hand 100 times. It's more logical for me.

Comment: `for()` will "return NULL invisibly" (from `help("for")`). This is how the control flow works. Outside the control flow, a returned value (in many contexts) will be printed to the console (or `show`n), but not so within the control flow.